# Seek help, "error: GC operation on unregistered thread. Thread registered implicitly."

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, garbage-collection, webview, malloc

I hit this error "malloc: *** auto malloc[731]: error: GC operation on unregistered thread. Thread registered implicitly. Break on auto_zone_thread_registration_error() to debug."

My app works like this , when users double click a row in NSTableView, it will get a URL from that row, then ask WebView to load page from that URL:

```
[tableView setDoubleAction:@selector(doubleClickAction:)]; 
...

- (IBAction)doubleClickAction:(id)sender { 
   ...
   /* cause that malloc error */
   [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: row.url]];   
}
```

So how do I fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: did you add the auto_zone_thread_registration_error breakpoint?

Comment: The app does not crash. I am new to cocoa development, I actaully do not know what does "Break on auto_zone_thread_registration_error() to debug" mean exactly. I added a break on that line, after I stepped out the line and type "bt" command, gdb can print out call trace, everything seems normal . Then after a while the error pops up and GDB does not response to bt command anymore. So how do I further debug ?

Comment: Are you creating threads yourself? If so, how?

Comment: No I did not create thread myself

Answer (score 4):

So I got a reply from https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=59938, "This was fixed back in r81825.  It’s a harmless message that can be ignored."

Answer (score 1):

Add this `objc_registerThreadWithCollector();` to your pthread. In case you cannot find a symbol or linking error, use following code,

```
 #include <dlfcn.h>
    void (*registerThreadWithCollector_fn)(void);
    registerThreadWithCollector_fn = (void(*)(void)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "objc_registerThreadWithCollector");
    if (registerThreadWithCollector_fn) {
        (*registerThreadWithCollector_fn)();
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
```

Comment: do we need to unregistered it too or it will happen automatically ?